# Stacknavigatior navigating to a screen, which is already in stack

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to figure out displaying a screen with new information, which is already in stack.

The screen order is like

Profile A -> Followers List of Profile A (clicking on Profile B) -> Profile B -> Followers List of Profile B

Profile and Followers List are both screen files. When I switch screens, if the screen is already in stack, it goes to the previous one. For example, when I click on "Profile B" in "Followers list of Profile A", it goes back and shows "Profile A",because the profile screen is already in stack.

How can I generate a new screen which can be added to the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Try navigate using `push` with adding extra key.

For example :

```js
this.props.navigation.push('ProfileB', {
    // others param, 
    key: maths.random().toString()
});
```

Note: do not use id of followers here, because if you click on same follower then it will match same idea, so it may be can go back. Which is not good. So used any random keys.

Answer (score 0):

`react-navigation-stack` has 3 way of navigation between screens:

`navigate`: standard navigation, if you are navigating to a new screen not in stack, it pushes it in the so-said stack. If you navigate to a screen that's already been mounted, it will pop back to it.

`replace`: Takes thes current component and replaces it with the one you want to navigate

`push`: pushes a new component to the stack, creating a new instace of it.

Imaging a stack that's like:

```
screen 3
screen 2
screen 1
```

Using push you will be able to start another instace of screen 1.

```
this.props.navigation.push("screen 1")
```

Will leave the stack as:

```
screen 1
screen 3
screen 2
screen 1
```

The problem with this method is that, if navigating back, you'll be brought to the previous instances of the screen with the old data